# Transpose rows to columns in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, transpose

I have a table which looks like the following

```
po_num   | terms type  | terms description
-------------------------------------------
10       | 1           | Desc-10-1
10       | 2           | Desc-10-2
10       | 3           | Desc-10-3
20       | 1           | Desc-20-1
20       | 3           | Desc-20-3
30       |             |
```

So, for each Purchase Order (PO_NUM) there could be several terms of agreements (maximum three - 1,2,3) or no terms of agreement at all. Now, what I need is to transpose rows into columns - that is, for each po_num, I would like to have a similar output like below.

```
po_num  | terms1      | termsDesc2  | terms2     | termsDesc2  | terms3    |termsDesc3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10       | 1           | Desc-10-1  | 2          | Desc-10-2   | 3         |Desc10-3
20       | 1           | Desc-20-1  |            |             | 3         |Desc20-3
30       |             |            |            |             |           |
```

I cannot use pivot since I don't have Oracle 11.2 installed. I do not wanna use scalar subqueries in the select because the performance degrades several times with that approach. I tried to use the following query to first concatenate all the fields, the split them with an outer query, but haven't been able to do it yet.

```
    SELECT po_num,
         RTRIM (
            XMLAGG (
               XMLELEMENT (
                  po_table,
                  po_table.terms_id || '|' || po_table.terms_description || '|')).
            EXTRACT ('//text()'),
            '|')
            po_concat
    FROM po_table
   WHERE 1 = 1
   GROUP BY PO_table.po_num
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 10g you can use `DECODE` function instead of `PIVOT`:

```
CREATE TABLE po_table (
  po_num NUMBER,
  terms_type NUMBER,
  terms_description VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 1, 'Desc-10-1');
INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 2, 'Desc-10-2');
INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 3, 'Desc-10-3');
INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(20, 1, 'Desc-20-1');
INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(20, 3, 'Desc-20-3');
INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(30, NULL, NULL);

COMMIT;

SELECT
    po_num,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 1, terms_type)) AS terms1,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 1, terms_description)) AS terms1Desc,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 2, terms_type)) AS terms2,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 2, terms_description)) AS terms2Desc,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 3, terms_type)) AS terms3,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 3, terms_description)) AS terms3Desc
  FROM
    po_table
GROUP BY po_num
ORDER BY po_num;
```

Output:

```
    PO_NUM  TERMS1 TERMS1DESC    TERMS2 TERMS2DESC    TERMS3 TERMS3DESC
---------- ------- ------------ ------- ------------ ------- ----------
        10       1 Desc-10-1          2 Desc-10-2          3 Desc-10-3 
        20       1 Desc-20-1                               3 Desc-20-3 
        30
```

Comment: thank you! Could you please explain the "trick" here? What's MAX got to do with pivoting?

Comment: @Ahmedov What we really want is to aggregate values from multiple rows for each `po_num`, and move the `terms_type` and `terms_description` into separate columns. We have to use the `GROUP BY` clause. Since we have to put everything that is not used in aggregate functions in the select list in the `GROUP BY` list, we enclose the `terms_type` values in any of the aggregate function, just to grab its value. You could use `MIN` here, it doesn't matter, since for each `po_num` there are only three possible values of `terms_type` (1, 2, 3), and DECODE is used to you put each of them in a diff. col.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
po_num,
MAX(CASE WHEN terms_id=1 THEN terms_description ELSE '' END) as termsDesc1, 
MAX(CASE WHEN terms_id=2 THEN terms_description ELSE '' END) as termsDesc2,
MAX(CASE WHEN terms_id=3 THEN terms_description ELSE '' END) as termsDesc3

FROM po_table
GROUP BY po_num
```